# Engine_version: Redis versions must match <major>.x when using version 6 or higher, or <major>.<minor>.<bug-fix>

Tags: redis, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the following elasticache resource:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_subnet_group" "main" {
  name       = "${var.identifier}-sng"
  subnet_ids = var.subnet_ids
}

resource "aws_elasticache_cluster" "main" {
  cluster_id           = var.identifier
  engine               = "redis"
  node_type            = var.node_type
  num_cache_nodes      = var.nodes_count
  parameter_group_name = var.parameter_group_name
  engine_version       = var.engine_version
  port                 = 6379
  security_group_ids   = var.security_group_ids
  subnet_group_name    = aws_elasticache_subnet_group.main.name

  tags = {
    "redis" = "Auto managed by TF"
  }
}
```

I run with aws elasticache Redis 6.0.5 and my var.engine_version is set with 6.0.5 too. It worked quite well until I've upgraded from terraform 1.3 to 1.4 I received the following error:

```
engine_version: Redis versions must match <major>.x when using version 6 or higher,
or <major>.<minor>.<bug-fix>
```

Is there anyone experiencing this issue after upgrading? what would be a solution to work around this problem?

Comment: `engine_version = "6.x"` does the trick.

Comment: did it work @channa ly?

Comment: @JuanFontes No. but If I disabled the engine_version and then run terraform apply and finally I put it back with engine_version = "6.x" it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem and I was able to fix by setting `parameter_group_name` family to `6.x` and `engine_version` to 6.0. When I set the engine version to 6.0.5 it threw the error you listed above. The 6.0 engine version defaults to 6.0.5

Answer (score 1):

just write the version number.x (ex - 7.x)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

According to the current docs, the format for `engine_version` differs between version.

- Version 7: Major and Minor **should** be set.
- Version 6: Major and Minor **could** be set. The minor can be left
  unspecified (no patch here)
- Version 5 or lower: Specify the full version desired, e.g., 5.0.6

This worked for us:

```
engine_version = "6.2",
parameter_group_name = "default.redis6.x"
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_cluster#engine_version

Answer (score 0):

I was using elasticache redis 6.2.6 and 7.0.4 for 2 different projects.
To make it work I had to set the engine_versions 6.2 and 7.0 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

After passing a "null" value to the engine_version parameter, Terraform defaulted to the latest engine version, which is 7.0.5. As a result of this change, Terraform executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

faced similar version issue as mentioned above while upgrading from version 5 to 6 or 7 above Major version.
I set below parameters to 6.x to overcome this issue.

- parameter_group_name    = "default.redis6.x"
- engine_version          = "6.x"

[![output][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vGaK.png

Note: it not worked for 7.x getting 400 error code.